# Typescript access value of generic type using key constrained by the type of that value

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a typescript function that takes a generic type and a key for that generic type. I constrain that key so that the function will only accept keys where the values will be of a certain type. When accessing the generic object using the constrained key I don't get the expected type in return.

How do you constrain a key of a generic object to a specific value type and access that value in a generic function?

For example:

```
function onlyTakesADateKey<T, K extends keyof T>(item: T, key: T[K] extends Date ? K : never): void {
    //I've constrained `key` to ensure that item[key] is a Date but this doesn't get typed as a Date
    const shouldBeADateButIsNot = item[key]
    //Property 'getTime' does not exist on type 'T[T[K] extends Date ? K : never]'.ts(2339)
    shouldBeADateButIsNot.getTime()
}
const foo = { key1: "asdf", key2: new Date() }
//Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.ts(2345)
const bar = onlyTakesADateKey(foo, "key1")
//It properly constrains the key, but per above can't access the date value in the function
const baz = onlyTakesADateKey(foo, "key2")
```

Why isn't `shouldBeADateButIsNot` a `Date`? The key is properly constrained. I cannot pass arguments to the function that result it in *not* being a Date.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler isn't really able to do much with [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types) that depend on as-yet-unspecified [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) type parameters like `T` and `K` inside the implementation of `onlyTakesADateKey`.  Inside the function implementation, evaluation of the type `T[K] extends Date ? K : never` is *deferred*.  That's why you see an error about `T[T[K] extends Date ? K : never]`. The compiler is unable to do the higher-order reasoning necessary to conclude that it must be assignable to `Date`.  It's a design limitation of TypeScript, as can be seen in [microsoft/TypeScript#30728](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30728).

The compiler often defers evaluation of types that depend on unspecified generics, but there are a few places where it can do a bit better.  One is: if you have a value of type `Record<K, V>` and index into it with `K`, the compiler will understand that it is of type `V`.  So generic lookups are not always completely deferred.  This suggests rewriting your `T` and `K` constraints like this:

```
function onlyTakesADateKey<T extends Record<K, Date>, K extends PropertyKey>(
  item: T, key: K): void {
    const isActuallyADateNow = item[key]
    isActuallyADateNow.getTime()
}
```

This works without error, and your examples behave similarly:

```
const foo = { key1: "asdf", key2: new Date() }
const baz = onlyTakesADateKey(foo, "key2"); // okay
```

with the notable exception that when you make a mistake, the compiler complains about `item` and not `key`:

```
const bar = onlyTakesADateKey(foo, "key1"); // error!
// -------------------------> ~~~
// Types of property 'key1' are incompatible.
```

---

If you really don't want to change anything about your call, you can always use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to just tell the compiler what it can't figure out: that `shouldBeADateButIsNot` is a `Date`:

```
function onlyTakesADateKeyOrig<T, K extends keyof T>(
  item: T, key: T[K] extends Date ? K : never): void {
    const shouldBeADateButIsNot = item[key] as any as Date;
    shouldBeADateButIsNot.getTime()
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAiQGwJ4BUCGBrAUwGcBBAERxgIGkCMB5AJzgHMAeLAGmWuQIA8qEACZFkhDAhDIsAPgAUcKgFsAXDO4T1WANrUAun0EERYilWQB+HsnUQCANwKMAlOocI4w5AG9gyAOQoJCIYZCIACwQwNGEAIQJySgI4sBgASSIAOQQwgF5kJQJlHQlDHDEcCAxkCuRzAgBuf0DI6NiEpKpUjOzcgDoWAhgsOGUCeRdgAF9gUEhYRBR0bHxiLpo6DiMhUWQAJQJgxmE2am4G2W5eAV2xAAVGBAAHZxgMWgwFIrUNcTp1NQ3MgPF5fHNAkEQmE4KRYGAcGhMBscgB3ZAFH6lOj6FoBWEkeGI5ENNGDYajcaTGbAYIQULIEAIBAY3z-DAARnUACIKsIQNzNHQAEx2AjohqTZCzWnQ5AAIxwjFZK1whFIDU+8iZCG43IkHO5LkayAA9Ka+IwnowAITAc3IAC0zpdrrd7tdsmQAD9ffaLVgMK8xFJkM8nq9GO9kAByA0x2qMAiFaAIZTPShweVoAj9OZ0hmKgBeKogmDV601dG1zL1EmFRqAA)

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the great explanation!