# Typescript typesafe generic function to collect array to map based on specified property key

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-types

I am trying to write a typescript generic function which, passed an array `T[]` and a property key `TProp` where `TProp extends keyof T` and such that `T[TProp] extends PropertyKey`, will collect the elements of the array into a single object, with the value selected from the array element based on the specified property as the key mapping to the original object in the array (keeping latest if there are duplicates).

I have the following code so far

```
type KeysWithValueOfType<T, V> = keyof {
  [P in keyof T as T[P] extends V ? P : never]: P;
} &  
  keyof T;
  
export const CollectToMap = <
  TArray extends object,
  TProp extends KeysWithValsOfType<TArray, PropertyKey>,
  TKey extends PropertyKey = TArray[TProp]
>(
  arr: TArray[],
  property: TProp
): Partial<Record<TKey, TArray>> => {
  let result: Partial<Record<TKey, TArray>> = {};

  for (const element of arr) {
    result[element[property]] = element;
  }

  return result;
};
```

`KeysWithValueOfType` returns a union type of keys from `T` for which `T[Property] extends V`.

For example given the type `Person`

```
type Person = {
  name?: string;
  age: number;
  email: string;
  pets: string[];
};
```

`type PersonStringPropKeys = KeysWithValueOfType<Person, string>;` is equivalent to `type PersonStringPropKeys = 'email';` which looks right.

Using this in `CollectToMap` however, I am seeing compiler errors for the `TKey` type, highlighting `TArray[TProp]` with the error

> Type 'TArray[TProp]' does not satisfy the constraint 'PropertyKey'.
> Type 'TArray[KeysWithValsOfType<TArray, PropertyKey>]' is not assignable to type 'PropertyKey'.
> Type 'TArray[string] | TArray[number] | TArray[symbol]' is not assignable to type 'PropertyKey'.
> Type 'TArray[string]' is not assignable to type 'PropertyKey'.ts(2344)

Subsequently there is also a compiler error on the line `result[element[property]] = element;` with the error

> Type 'TArray[TProp]' cannot be used to index type 'Partial<Record<TKey, TArray>>'.ts(2536)

It seems that I have wrongly expressed the semantics I'm trying to convey, or that the compiler is unable to follow that if `TProp` is a `keyof T` where `T[TProp] extends PropertyKey` it can therefore be used in the way I'm intending to index into the Record.

What's strange is that writing a simple test example using the function, the compiler does seem to give correct suggestions for the keys which are valid, and infer the correct types.

[image: VSCode intellisense of usage of CollectToMap function]

[image: VSCode intellisense of usage of CollectToMap with property key specified]

Comment: You have two separate issues.  One is that the compiler cannot do the higher order operation of seeing that `T[KeysMatching<T, V>]` is a subtype of `V`, as mentioned in [ms/TS#30728](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30728), and so that part's a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66483867/2887218). The other is that your third type parameter is just *defaulting* to `TArray[TProp]` so the compiler cannot know that `element[property]` is assignable to it; you don't need a third type parameter.  See [this code](https://tsplay.dev/wOJ0zW) which fixes both.

Comment: Does that meet your needs? If so I can maybe write up an answer, although it's nice when SO questions have one main issue and not two. Do you want to make the question about just one of those things?  (e.g., fix one of them in the question so the answer could focus on the other)

Comment: That's really helpful, thanks @jcalz.  I had considered trying to express in that way but I had (clearly mistakenly) assumed that I couldn't have a TArray and TProp reference each other.  In terms of teasing the question apart into two, I'm not sure how would be best to express the two different issues concisely so as to be helpful to ohers searching in future

Comment: [This example code](https://tsplay.dev/WKVxym) shows two different ways to frame the problem depending on the question you really need solved.  If you want to pare down the question code to one of those I’m happy to address the single issue.  Good luck!